# Using AFOpenFlow: adding subviews not just images

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, coverflow

I am using the AFOpenFlow library to generate a coverflow-like effect, but trying to add arbitrary UIViews to an AFOpenflowView, not just images. I am doing this by creating a subclass of of `AFItemView`, lets call it `NewAFItemView`, which represents the view I want to add. I also extended `AFOpenFlowView`, call it `NewAFOpenFlowView` and overrode the method

```
-(AFItemView *)coverForIndex:(int)coverIndex;
```

In the overridden method, I allocate an `NewAFItemView` object and return it as the cover view for that index. The `NewAFItemView` views appear correctly in the open flow but scrolling is immediately disabled. Switching back to allocating `AFItemView`s works but using `NewAFItemView`s does not scroll.

I have not overridden any of the touch events.

Any ideas on what might be happening?

Cheers.

Comment: Do you mean scrolling from one cover to the next is disable, or scrolling within your custom AFItemView?

Comment: did you solve the problem? i´m interesting in using afopenflow with views instead of uiimages, and i can´t make it work

Comment: Hey Ziggy I did resolve this issue. The solution I used was drawing the UIView to an image and then using that image as the AFOpenFlowView Item using this method
`+ (UIImage *) imageWithView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    
    return image;
}`

Comment: Then use that image in `setImage:(UIImage *)image forIndex:(int)index` for the `AFOpenflowView`

Answer (score 0):

why don´t you use iCarousel?
https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel
i use this, and it works perfect for uiviews =).

Comment: when u download it there is more than one application so plz tell me which one of them u use , because i have the same issue ???